# Express restful api expecting json array

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to integrate an Excel spreadsheet with my application using an node.js Express Restful Api. My API already accepts simple json like:

```
{
  "num": "1",
  "name": "Adams"
}
```

But now i need to send array of objects like:

```
[
   {
       "num": 1,
       "name": "Adams"
   },
   {
       "num": 2,
       "name": "Phillips"
   }
]
```

I'm using mongoose to connect to a mongoDB server and already the following function connected to a route in my api to accept single objects:

```
create_a_budget: function (req, res) {
    var budget = new budgetModel({
        user_id : req.body.user_id,
        seq_budget : req.body.seq_budget,
        date_done : req.body.date_done,
        num_budget : req.body.num_budget,
        medium : req.body.medium,
        client_name : req.body.client_name,
        email : req.body.email
    });

    budget.save(function (err, budget) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Error when creating budget',
                error: err
            });
        }
        return res.status(201).json(budget);
    });
}
```

But i don't have a clue about how to treat the array

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass an array of documents received from mongodb in res.json. res.json() will handle array properly. You dont have to do anything else. Example of the same:-

```
db.budget.find(query, (err, budgets) {
  if(err) {
   // handle error
  }
  return res.status(200).json(budgets);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand... i want to save various objects in one shot, not find

Comment: Ohh okay. That’s also fine you can just pass an array of documents to be saved in budget.create([...budgets]). You have to use create method instead of save. Please look up for create method on mongoose docs